# What happens when an hazelcast cluster only contains lite members?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using hazelcast in a Java Desktop project, to synchronize in real time shared data among 1 to 6 clients. I store a map of about 200 entries, with the corresponding state (free / busy) so that two clients cannot reserve the same item at the same time.

Since the client hardware is not omogeneous, in order to optimize performance I configured the slowest members to be [lite members](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.3/manual/single_html/#LiteMember). This seems to improve response times.

However, I noticed that if i set ALL the member as lite members (e.g. without storage), the shared maps appears to be working correctly anyway. So my question is: what are the implications of an hazelcast cluster composed only of lite members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all members are lite, a properly working cluster is not possible as there is no place to put data.

How do you set member as lite member?

Do you see the 'lite' message on cluster formation such as:

```
Members [2] {
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 this lite
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5702 lite
}
```

Comment: I understood what happened: I used the -Dhazelcast.lite.member=true switch with hazelcast-1.9.4.4 where the flag is still named -Dhazelcast.super.client=true, so it was not having effect.

Comment: so, what does happen if the first client I launch is a lite one?